# Beginner level of hangman coding

Tags: java, string

I am making a hangman program for my practice and i am halting at how to print the correct character entered by user with the partial answer.Every thing is working optimally, just need help in concatenation.?????????? is to map the place for which I need the logic.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class hangman{
public static void main(String args[]){

int counter=6;
String m="ashish";
char mj[] = m.toCharArray();


//for printing the puzzle 
for(int j=0;j<m.length();j++)
{

if(mj[j]%3==0)
    {   
      System.out.print(" "+mj[j]);
     }
else   System.out.print(" ___ ");
 }    
  System.out.println();

//taking the input from user
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

do{
char c=scanner.next().charAt(0);

   System.out.println(c+"-----scanning complete");
   for(int i=0;i<m.length();i++)
    {
     if(c==mj[i])
     {
  String n= ?????????????????????;

           counter--; }   

    }while(counter != 0);
     }}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use an IDE with auto-formatting.

Comment: You say "everything is working" -- I see this giant expression containing question marks which would never compile on any machine I know of.  I'm not so sure it's "working".

Comment: except that if you would remove it that i have already checked is working fine just need the logic which can replace these question marks.
Question mark is to map the part for which i need the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save some sort of array of characters the player has got correct.
Try something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class hangman {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int counter = 6;
    String m = "ashish";
    char mj[] = m.toCharArray();
    char correct[] = new char[mj.length];


    //for printing the puzzle 
    for(int j=0;j<m.length();j++) {
        if(mj[j]%3==0) {   
            System.out.print(" "+mj[j]);
            correct[j] = mj[j];
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(" ___ ");
        }
    }    

    System.out.println();

    //taking the input from user
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        char c=scanner.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println(c+"-----scanning complete");
        for(int i=0;i<m.length();i++) {
            if(c==mj[i]) {
                correct[i] = c;
                counter--;
            }
            // This is the default value of a char in Java.
            if (correct[i] == '\u0000') {
                System.out.print(" ___ "); 
            } else {
                System.out.print(correct[i]);
            }
        }

    } while(counter != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sanketh! I know this is not complete logical code ,but I am a beginner and thank you helped me out , now i can edit to make it more better.